Calculating the number of values ​from a relation table based on a date range
table bayarlanjas
| tglbayar   | bayarlanja |user_id|
| ---------- | ---------- |-------|
| 2024-01-05 |     10     |   1   |
| 2024-02-06 |     20     |   1   |
| 2024-03-07 |     30     |   1   |
| 2024-04-08 |     40     |   1   |

table zakats
| tglawalhaul| tglakhirhaul |user_id|
| ---------- | ------------ |-------|
| 2024-01-01 |  2024-02-25  |   1   |
| 2024-03-01 |  2024-04-25  |   1   |


which I tried
SELECT
  zakats.*,
  bayarlanjas.user_id,
  sum(bayarlanja) AS total_bayar
FROM
  `zakats`
  LEFT JOIN `bayarlanjas` ON `bayarlanjas`.`user_id` = `zakats`.`user_id`
WHERE
  `bayarlanjas`.`tglbayar` BETWEEN zakats.tglawalhaul
  AND zakats.tglakhirhaul
  AND `zakats`.`user_id` = 1
GROUP BY
  `bayarlanjas`.`user_id`


But Error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated

What I want

| tglawalhaul| tglakhirhaul |total_bayar|user_id|
| ---------- | ------------ |-----------|-------|
| 2024-01-01 |  2024-02-25  |     30    |   1   |
| 2024-03-01 |  2024-04-25  |     70    |   1   |



Try this:
SELECT
  zakats.tglawalhaul,
  zakats.tglakhirhaul,
  zakats.user_id,
  SUM(bayarlanjas.bayarlanja) AS total_bayar
FROM
  zakats
LEFT JOIN bayarlanjas ON bayarlanjas.user_id = zakats.user_id
  AND bayarlanjas.tglbayar BETWEEN zakats.tglawalhaul AND zakats.tglakhirhaul
WHERE
  zakats.user_id = 1
GROUP BY
  zakats.tglawalhaul,
  zakats.tglakhirhaul,
  zakats.user_id

